# Java Object.equals

Tags: java, object, equals

Can someone tell me why this returns true ?
I thought if I cast something to e.g. `Object` and then call `.equals`,
the default implementation from `Object` will be used. And s1 == s2 should return false.

Please tell me under which topic I can find more about this behavior.

```
   Set<String> s1 = new HashSet<String>(as("a"));
   Set<String> s2 = new HashSet<String>(as("a"));

   Object o1 = (Object)s1;
   Object o2 = (Object)s2;

   System.out.println(o1.equals(o2));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Methods in Java are virtual by default. In particular, `Object.equals` is virtual (since it's not declared [`final`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29#Final_methods)). Since [`HashSet` overrides `Object.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)<sup>1</sup>, you'll see the `HashSet` implementation of `equals` used when you invoke the virtual method on an object that has a runtime type of `HashSet` (remember [dynamic dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch) depends on the *runtime* type of the receiving object, not the compile-time type).

<sup>1</sup>: We know that `HashSet` overrides `Object.equals` because the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) says that `HashSet` derives from `AbstractSet` and the documentation for [`AbstractSet.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)  says:

> Compares the specified object with this set for equality. Returns `true` if the specified object is also a set, the two sets have the same size, and every member of the specified set is contained in this set (or equivalently, every member of this set is contained in the specified set). This definition ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the set interface.

which clearly defines *value* equality whereas the default `Object.equals` is *identity* equality.

Answer (score 5):

Because that's exactly what the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) say it will do:

> public boolean equals(Object o)
>   Compares the specified object with this set for equality. Returns true if the given object is also a set, the two sets have the same size, and every member of the given set is contained in this set. This ensures that the equals method works properly across different implementations of the Set interface.

Just because you cast it to `Object` doesn't change what it actually is. The over-ridden `equals()` method in `HashSet` is used.

Answer (score 2):

Because, of **Polymorphism**.

At runtime, the actual type of object determines which implementation of an *instance* method should execute. Since, `HashSet` inherits an *overridden* implementation from `AbstractSet` it's used for comparison instead of `Object.equals()`

And, the JavaDocs for [AbstractSet#equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) state

> Returns true if the given object is also a set, the two sets have the same size, and every member of the given set is contained in this set.

Hence, your equality test prints *true*.

So, the type of reference (*Object*, in your case) has little bearing on which version of `equals()` is invoked at runtime. It entirely depends on the *type* of object your reference is pointing to.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the default implementation of equals should return you false. But here default implementation is not called. Object class is extended by everytype in java and that includes HashSet.

Now here if you see, you are referring HashSet object with Object class reference. And hence HashSet equals is called. And hence it returns true.